# Entropy and encrypted files

Tags: file, entropy

I have a question and need help.
Usually, in encrypted files, the file size is larger than the unencrypted  file. Does entropy decrease at these times? I know the entropy is calculated like below in python:

```
print('myfile.text'.format)
with open(r"C:\Users\Parisa\Desktop\myfile.txt", 'rb') as f:
byteArr = list(f.read())
fileSize = len(byteArr)
print
print('File size in bytes: {:,d}'.format(fileSize))
# calculate the frequency of each byte value in the file
print('Calculating Shannon entropy of file. Please wait...')
freqList = []
for b in range(256):
    ctr = 0
    for byte in byteArr:
        if byte == b:
            ctr += 1
    freqList.append(float(ctr) / fileSize)
# Shannon entropy
ent = 0.0
for freq in freqList:
    if freq > 0:
        ent = ent + freq * math.log(freq, 2)
ent = -ent
print('Shannon entropy: {}'.format(ent))[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]stack.imgur.com/jMhkc.png
this is after encryption

[image]

this is before encryption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entropy of the encrypted file is maximised. Entropy being a measure of "randomness" of the file.

This is how a text file usually looks, graphing entropy against the file contents:

[image]

This is how an encrypted file looks (ignore the tiny spike to low entropy, it was caused by some header information or equivalent):

[image]

Encrypted files have entropy near 1. If they didn't they wouldn't be well encrypted. Patterns == lower entropy, and lower entropy == bad encryption.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But does the entropy decrease if the size of the encrypted file exceeds the unencrypted file?

Comment: No it most certainly does not. Even if the size of the encrypted file is larger, entropy will not decrease.

Comment: I'm so sorry for asking many questions. Is it possible for entropy to decrease but chi-square to increase in the encrypted file?

Comment: Are you trying to test the dependance of the encrypted file on its plaintext using chi-square? I don't understand why chi-square comes into this?

Comment: Yes, and can we say that if the chi-square of the encrypted file increases compared to the chi-square of the unencrypted file then good encryption is done?

Comment: Well it makes sense then for chi-square and entropy to increase together! This is what we'd expect. Cryptanalysis has to be based on more than just chi-square, but its an indicator.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean that good cryptography is cryptography that increases entropy and chi-square?

Comment: I think a better way to state it is, good cryptography turns plaintext into cipher text, indistinguishable from random, i.e. entropy of 1.  - Chi Square is just the delta between the distributions.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. So you think entropy is a better measure

Comment: Yep I do, even better again is a rigorous math proof. Happy to help :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @ph9675 you're welcome :) good and easy read here: https://cryptologie.net/article/173/how-can-you-tell-if-a-cipher-is-secure/

Comment: Hello, Can I ask a question? I have a file and after encryption, the graph of entropy is like this / is it good?

Comment: I can't see the picture?

Comment: Excuse me. I can't send in the comment, I add the figures to the question but But I showed it as a line(/)

Comment: I add pictures to the question.

Comment: @ph9675 what are the axis?

Comment: The vertical axis is the entropy and the horizontal axis is equal to the output, which after each entropy is taken from the above formula dd.append (-ent) is kept as this, it is the size of dd so that I can draw the graph

Comment: Is there any problem in histograms?

Comment: @ph9675 entropy should be 1.0 (on a scale of 0-1) for encrypted data. It should be indistinguishable from random.

Comment: Thank you. But how can it be calculated for a file?

Comment: grab this tool: https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk, run `binwalk --entropy <file>`

Answer (score 0):

You've really touched on something difficult. Let me quote some dude from the past:-

> “My greatest concern was what to call it. I thought of calling it ‘information’, but the word was overly used, so I decided to call it ‘uncertainty’. When I discussed it with John von Neumann, he had a better idea. Von Neumann told me, “You should call it entropy, for two reasons. In the first place your uncertainty function has been used in statistical mechanics under that name, so it already has a name. In the second place, and more important, nobody knows what entropy really is, so in a debate you will always have the advantage.”

-Claude Shannon.

As discussed [elsewhere](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87612/23115) 'entropy' usually increases when you encrypt a source/plain text. I probably didn't dive into the detail, but in line with the quote above, there are varying definitions on entropy. Especially in cryptography. The cipher text will look more complex.

---

Use `ent` from [here](https://www.fourmilab.ch/random/).

Comment: Thanks for introducing ent and your help.